# Storing anonymous users' favorites on Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am new to Redis and started playing with it.

I have a rails app where unauthenticated users can put newspaper articles as favorites, so they could read them later. What I have been doing until now is storing the favorites in cookies.

But I would like to achieve the same with Redis.
There is the command `lset`. What I don't understand is if this list will be unique to each visitor or common to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Redis is a key-value database, if you use same key for every user - then list will be common for everyone. Uniqueness can be achieved by adding some user id into the key.

If you want to add an article id to users' list - `RPUSH` is more suitable, because you do not know which list index the article will be at.

Other problem is data expiration, because anonymous users' data is useless once the user clears their cookies/change browser etc. In this respect cookie storage is more preferred. If you worry about cookies size - you may look into using localStorage on clientside. Also you can use rails' redis session storage - this way cookies only contain session id and all data goes to redis (where rails will care for it's structure, users are unlikely to face race conditions in your task)

Comment: I see, that makes sense.

Comment: I think you mean *Redis session storage*. I would also consider localstorage if cookie size is an issue.